How to solve $(x^2+x)y''+(2-x^2)y'-(2+x)y=x(x+1)^2$
I am trying to solve the following $(x^2+x)y''+(2-x^2)y'-(2+x)y=x(x+1)^2$.
To find the homogenous solution $y_{h}$ is the part I am having difficulties with, because if would have found $y_{h}$, then I would use variation of parameters to find a particular solution $y_{p}$.
To solve $(x^2+x)y''+(2-x^2)y'-(2+x)y=0$ I considered the substitution $$z(x)= ln \ (x) \implies 
 y' = \frac{1}{x} \frac{dz}{dx} \ \ \& \ \ y'' =  \frac{1}{x^2} (\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} -\frac{dz}{dx})$$
I got nowhere, so I instead tried the substitution $$y(x)=x*v(x) \implies y' = v\ +\ xv' \ \& \ y'' = 2v'\ + \ xv''$$
This gave me a nasty looking expression, which is why I think that this might be the wrong way to go.

Hint, method 1 By inspection the sum of the coefficients of $y'', y', y$ is zero, so $y(x) = e^x$ (which satisfies $y'' = y' = y$) satisfies the homogenized o.d.e.,
$$(x^2+x)y''+(2-x^2)y'-(2+x)y = 0 .$$
With that solution in hand, we substitute the ansatz $y(x) = e^x u(x)$, which leads to a first-order, linear, separable equation in $v := u'$:
$$(x^2 + x) v' + (x^2 + 2 x + 2) v = 0 .$$

Solving gives $u' = v = -B\frac{1 + x}{x e^x}$, and integrating gives $u = \frac{B}{x e^x}$, which corresponds to the solution $y(x) = \frac{B}{x}$. By linearity, the general solution to the homogeneous equation is $$y_h(x) = A e^x + \frac{B}{x} .$$

Hint, method 2 The form of the coefficients suggests trying a general power function as an ansatz: $y(x) = B x^n$. Substituting in the homogeneous equation and factoring gives
$$-B (n + 1) x^{n - 1} [x^2 + (2 - n) x - n] = 0,$$
and the solution $n = -1$ yields the family $\frac{B}{x}$ of solutions. With one solution in hand, we substitute the ansatz $y(x) = \frac1x w(x)$, which leads to a first-order, linear, separable equation in $z := w'$:
$$(x + 1) z' - (x + 2) z = 0 .$$

 Solving gives $w' = z = A (x + 1) e^x$, and integrating gives $w = A x e^x$, which corresponds to the solution $y(x) = A e^x$. By linearity, the general solution to the homogeneous equation is $$y_h(x) = A e^x + \frac{B}{x} .$$

Remark In fact, the left-hand side of the o.d.e. is a functional multiple of a Wronskian determinant, $$(x^2+x)y''+(2-x^2)y'-(2+x)y = -e^{-x} x^3 W\left(y(x), \exp x, \frac1x\right) .$$
We get immediately that this quantity vanishes precisely when $y(x)$ is a linear combination of $\exp x, \frac1x$.

Cool solution, but I would like to solve it without inspection.

I've added a second method that just uses substituting a standard ansatz to get an easy algebraic equation for the parameters.

Well, you could use the Frobenius method.  The indicial roots are $-1$ and $0$, and the recurrence should turn out to be rather simple.  You should get $1/x$ and $e^x$ as solutions of the homogeneous equation.

Thanks for the suggestion, I will look up this method.
